# ReSharper 6.0 Conflicting with Symantec Endpoint Protection

Tags: resharper-6.0, symantec, resharper-5.1

ReSharper 6.0 seems to be conflicting with Symantec Endpoint Protection on my XP Pro SP3 machine at work.  It causes the machine to automatically reboot after I randomly do things with ReSharper.  If I uninstall 6.0 and install 5.1.3, I see no problem whatsoever.

Anyone else ever encounter this?  Anyone know of a solution that would allow me to use 6.0?

I have already posted this question on the forum over at JetBrains (fyi)

JetBrains UPDATE:

There seems to be [other people encountering this same issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274232?projectKey=RSRP) (without mentioning Symantec). When anything happens to the issue at JetBrains, I will update this question here on stack!

Thanks!

Comment: Have your admin turn on memory dumps for your system. Send the dumps to Symantec.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing any errors in the Windows Event viewer? What features of SEP are installed on this system? You might try disabling one feature at a time to narrow down the cause of this issue. Also check the SEP logs for anything pointing to ReSharper.
Can you tell me What version of SEP are you running?

P.S. I responded to your tweet, so feel free to DM me there if you wish.

Comment: Does SEP monitor assembly (library) loads? If so, do you test with Visual Studio and other applications that load a large number of libraries? I had crashes from another vendors EP product some time ago, caused by bugs that only showed up when large numbers of assemblies were loaded. Was able to repro by loading and unloading all assemblies from program files.

Comment: I am seeing errors - 3 in fact. 1) MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS - FallBack certificate initialization failed with error code: 1. 2) Schannel - A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential private key... 3) DCOM - The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application with CLSID...

Comment: As far as I am aware - it is all on (work computer - not really allowed to modify it). Antivirus & Antispyware Protection, Proactive Threat Protection, and Network Threat Protection are all on.  It is version 11.0.5002.333.

Comment: It may not even be Symantec related after all.  There are other people who are encountering the same problem, and they do not mention Symantec at all - http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274232?projectKey=RSRP .  If anything comes up from this jetbrains issue, I will update this question on stack!

Comment: @DanAppleyard: keep in mind that ReSharper is user-mode code. It cannot crash your computer.